# I'm using SCADA-LTS and I want test MBus datasource

Tags: scada, scadalts

Is there any emulator available for MBus TCP/IP protocol.

Is somebody using this protocol in SCADA-BR or SCADA-LTS?

[image]

Please give me any suggestion how can I test this data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question you are seeking for an alternative to buying hardware M-Bus converter. Unfortunately for what I know there is no free software M-Bus emulator available. If you serious about M-Bus you may consider getting into contact with one of [many firms](http://www.m-bus.com/firmen/liste.php) offering services for M-Bus customers. However if you prefer Do-It-Yourself approach and are going to write such emulator yourself take a look at [libmbus library](http://www.rscada.se/libmbus/) (open source C library) using of which may greatly simplify such task.